# Getting docker image Tag while running Azure Resource Graph query for image vulnerability assessment

Tags: azure, docker, graph, resources

We are generating docker vulnerability assessment report using azure resource graph query, after writing kusto query to generate the report of list of dockerimages that have vulnerability we are geting details regarding the docker repository and its corresponding sha/digest value and other details as required but we need docker tag also for that particular repository/digets value which we are unable to get in the azure resource query, we need to have the docker image tag data as well in our report
Below is my kql query:

```
securityresources
| where type == "microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments"
| where id has "Assesment key" and isnotnull (properties.id)
| mv-expand properties.additionalData.cve
| mv-expand properties.additionalData.data
| mv-expand properties.additionalData.vendorReferences
| project Image=properties.additionalData.repositoryName, Digest=properties.additionalData.imageDigest, Dockertag=properties.additionalData.data.***, CVE=properties_additionalData_cve
```

can anyone tell what modifications we can make exactly in the *** section or some other way to get that data (Image Tag)?

Comment: appreciate if anyone can assist on this issue

Comment: I'm also interested in the solution. Meanwhile the example query doesn't work for me:
Query is invalid. ... (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure) When I leave out the last line, the query runs through, but without any results (which is not plausible).

Answer (score 0):

As far, as I know, the Vulnerability Scan results, from the [Qualys scanner used by MS for images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-vulnerability-assessment-azure), don't refer to image tags. They have a reference to the image manifest, by indicating the repository and the image digest.
As the Resource Graph does not seem to model ACR images, or even image repositories as resources or sub-resources, there seems to be no way using Resource Graph queries to get this information. Additionally you may have images which currently bear no tags at all and those still may have vulnerability scans available for them.

MS is also working on [their own solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/agentless-container-registry-vulnerability-assessment), which for now seems to be in preview for ACR. This seems to have a slightly different structure for sub-assessments and it does seem to contain reference to the image tags in the `properties.additionalData.artifactDetails.tags`.